# Fixing TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType' in Con function

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst

I am working with DHSVM model and to create the streammapfile I need to run a code but I got the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Rana\PhD in U of U\Spring_2018\Research_for_PhD\DHSVM_Files_Millcreek_01.02.2018\arcinfo\DHSVM\createstreamnetwork.py", line 177, in <module>
    tmpelev=Con(IsNull(elevras)==1,int(elevras.minimum),elev)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

The code is as follows:

```
env.mask="maskras"
tmpacc=Con(IsNull("flow_acc")==1,int(flowacc.maximum),"flow_acc")
ExtractMultiValuesToPoints(nodestart, [[tmpacc, "MAXGRID"]])
arcpy.AddField_management (streamnet, "downarc", "LONG")
ExtractMultiValuesToPoints(nodestart, [[elev, "SELEV"]], "NONE")
elevras=Raster(elev)
tmpelev=Con(IsNull(elevras)==1,int(elevras.minimum),elev)
ExtractMultiValuesToPoints(nodeend, [[tmpelev, "EELEV"]], "NONE")
env.mask = wshd
```

Comment: please format your code

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

`elevras.minimum` is `None` because statistics have not been calculated. You need to use the [Calculate Statistics tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/calculate-statistics.htm) on `elevras`.